# Embedded FTP Server with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, open-source, ftp

Is there any open source .NET-based (no Win32 native, ActiveX, COM+ etc) library so I will can easily set up a ftp server? It is going to be a ftp server that will update a SQL Server database, and not regular files.

Thank you.

Comment: im not lazy, I've found some - I'm looking for recommendations.

Comment: @Andrey - Not a helpful comment in this circumstance. Stackoverflow is meant to be a helpful community.

Comment: Please be sure to mark any helpful responses as answers.

Comment: Why, exactly, are you trying to make SQL work like FTP?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is worth mentioning the [Lumisoft.NET](http://www.lumisoft.ee/lswww/download/downloads/Net/) library which contains an FTP server component. I haven't used it myself but it appears to meet your requirements (100% managed FTP server library). As a bonus it is free for private **and** commercial use (similar to LGPL).

Comment: Just want to note, this Lumisoft.NET library is quite handy and lightweight, I got an FTP server setup for testing without too much effort.

Answer (score 0):

I am attempting to do a similar thing (FTP server getting files and folder structure from SQL database).  I've been using [darwen's FTP server on Code Guru](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/sockets/article.php/c7409/).

It does have some problems, notably cross threading issues, but with a little work these can be fixed.  Also of note is to check that it uses the correct format for the IP addresses.

I have found this works for connections from FileZilla, but as yet I haven't been able to connect to it directly from windows explorer.  I have been unable to find anything better for free.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/AdvancedFTPServer.aspx is very good

http://sourceforge.net/projects/xfftp/

Comment: xfftp requires xf.server.dll which is provided as a binary, but I'm unable to find its source. It's supposed to be available at www.kodart.com, but this site is gone.

Answer (score -1):

For my FTP needs I use [edtFTP](http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnet/overview.html).

Also, something you might want to look at is [FTPLib](http://www.jelovic.com/ftplib/index.html).

Both are free and .NET

Comment: Both these appear to be FTP Clients instead of FTP Servers.

Comment: initial request asks for ftp servers, not clients