# C# Embedded FTP Server

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I'm searching a library which allows me to embed a FTP Server in a C# application.

I've only very basic needs:

- Have the possibility to have at least one user/password
- Have an event on which I can register when someone has sent a file
- Need to configure the port/directory
- I need it to works with framework .Net 2.0
- Not too expensive

For the FTP, I only need they can send a file.

I've already made some research:

- http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_network/sockets/article.php/c7409
  -->  tested, but no command are working, I can't even list the content of the folder
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/psingh/FTPServerinCSharp11162005015958AM/FTPServerinCSharp.aspx --> Is just awful: I've saw that thread relative to the server and the client are coded in the same file
- http://www.remobjects.com/ip.aspx --> Didn't understand how to make something with this internet package, if I install it and start the demo applicatin, I've several failures which makes me impossible to test it
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/csftpserver/ --> Cannot download anything
- http://www.gotdotnet.com/Community/UserSamples/Details.aspx?SampleGuid=0a7606f3-f8ec-4e39-8d0e-517248b7164c --> not accessible
- http://forum.junowebdesign.com/general-programming/27873-%5Bc-%5D-ftp-server.html
  --> event when logged, I can't download the file

So is something existing for doing this like this??? Something you can recommend. I don't need to have great performances, ...

Thank you very much

Comment: See the suggestions in the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387352/embedded-ftp-server-with-c) and also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394620/ftp-server-written-in-c). If there don't seem to be any that are acceptable your best bet will to take an open-source one and work on the issues, or decide whether it *really* needs to be embedded?

Comment: I already checked your link, the first contains library for FTP Client component, or the one which is not unavailable anymore. On the second post, it contains the same one, and I've tried all of them(and listed here).

I need it to be embedded, because it will be set into a plugin of another really biggest program which has already some interface I've to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTPSBlackbox package of our [SecureBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-ftps.php) product (.NET edition) lets you create both simple and sophisticated FTP and FTPS (FTP-over-SSL) servers. Components have only managed code and let you use any socket class you want (including our sockets, which support various proxies).

If you need SFTP server in future, we have one as well.

Comment: Funny, I was trying it right now. For the moment, it's the best I've tested, I used mostly the TElSimpleFTPSServer(because I don't want/need to have). Is there any way to edit the Welcome message?

Comment: @J4N Of course, welcome message can be changed and our developers will tell you how to do this. Please use our support channels ( http://www.eldos.com/sbb/support-tech.php ) for support.